# Cutting of audio files

Tags: software-recommendation, sound

I was looking for software which is able to cut audio files into smaller pieces, for example I set seconds and miliseconds for beginning and end of cutting, and then I can save cut content as new file.

Comment: For Kubuntu 18.04 it worked for me: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/amd64/libav-tools/7:3.3.4-2

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Audacity](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Audacity) is capable of doing this.

About Audacity

Audacity is a free, easy-to-use and multilingual audio editor and recorder for Windows, Mac OS X, GNU/Linux and other operating systems. You can use Audacity to:

- Record live audio.
- Convert tapes and records into digital recordings or CDs.
- Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files.
- Cut, copy, splice or mix sounds together.
- Change the speed or pitch of a recording.
- And more! See the complete [list of features](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features).

[image]

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get install audacity` to install it quickly

Comment: or `sudo dnf install audacity`

Answer (score 18):

avconv can do this.

Example:

```
avconv -i infile.m4a  -ss *pos* -t *duration* outfile.mp3
```

*pos* is start time in seconds

*duration* is play time in seconds

Install libav-tools to make it happen.

---

If you are not sure about the start and end times and want to listen to the segment before making it a new file, you should know that `avplay` takes many of the same arguments as `avconv` does.

Example:

```
avplay -ss 5030 -t 970 infile.m4a
```

If you don't want to do math in your head and also would not like to pull up a calculator, you can use the Hour:Minute:Second format instead. The example given above would then be:

```
avplay -ss 1:23:50 -t 00:16:10 infile.m4a
```

Also, keep in mind that if the pieces are not the final output (e.g. you are going to combine them), you might want to keep using the same format as that of the input file.

Comment: `libav-tools` is not available with `apt install` or `snap install`. ubuntu 18.04

Comment: libav-tools now embedded in ffmpeg. After `apt-get install ffmpeg` you need to resurrect some of the applications with `cd /usr/bin && sudo ln ffmpeg avconv && sudo ln ffmpeg avprobe`

Answer (score 5):

Somehow for me, the following worked extremely well

```
sudo apt-get install mpgtx
```

Once this is done, change the current directory to the directory where input.mp3 is located and then run the following:

```
mpgsplit input.mp3 [hh:mm:ss-hh:mm:ss] -o output.mp3
```

Comment: Does not work for me: range `[00:00:00-01:42:55] results in invalid [-1-98799992] range` - what is wrong? File is 3h long.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using mplayer

```
mplayer -quiet \
sourcefile.mp4 -ao pcm:fast:file=output.wav \
-vc dummy -vo null -channels 2 \
-ss 1:00 -endpos 0:30
```

note that output file will start from 1:00 for a duration of 30 seconds.

`-endpos` here means duration.

Answer (score -2):

i've never use this, but it looks great
[Lmms](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) &
[manual wiki](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/0.4%3aManual)