# Is there and software to split and rearrange an audio file easily?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound-editor

I am looking for software that allows me to load an audio file make splits in it. I would like to then rearrange it to change what someone said :). I have seen many videos online where people have done it and I cannot figure out how. It would be nice to change pitches and other things like that but those are not necessities

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/49799/cutting-of-audio-files - Audacity appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I too vote for Audacity, available via apt-get or synaptic

Comment: Please write it as an answer so I can make it the solution :). THANK YOU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly for simple splitting Audacity is the easiest gui tool to use. Using an example on my own setup:

1. First import your audio into Audacity
2. Drag your cursor along and select a segment of the audio
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and label the segment
4. Repeat for other segments and also label appropriately, my example is labelled simply 'Part 1' and 'Part 2":

[image]

4. You mentioned changing pitches and other effects, have a look now at the 'Effects' menu and you will see a truly amazing set of effects that can be applied to the output audio. First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select *all* segments (or select the segments individually with mouse click) and then apply any of these effects:

[image]

The 'Reverse' effect is my personal favourite!

5. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to simply export the 2 segments as separate files in the format of your choice with the meta tagging of your choice
6. If you wish however to rearrange the splits *before* exporting this can be done as a simple cut and paste. See here, using the same audio file, I have reversed the audio and you can see that the waveforms are now chopped in half and replaced out of order:

[image]

And now export the *whole* 'reversed-segment' file with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Hopefully I have addressed all of your points? Endless fun to be had with Audacity :)

**References:**

- [Splitting a recording for export as separate tracks](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/splitting_a_recording_into_separate_tracks.html)

Answer (score 2):

audacity may be able to do what you want (and more, also does the optional things you had)... http://www.audacityteam.org

Answer (score 1):

From command line the tool you want to play with is called **sox**

Installed as an apt-get command - this is a VERY useful and flexible interface.